# Py GTK not being installed

Tags: python, pygtk

https://pypi.org/project/PyGTK

> I went to this link and copied the latest pip install but it gives me
> this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyGTK (from versions: 2.24.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyGT
```

Comment: PyGTK depopends on GTK, so depending on you operative system, you would need install it. If you are on windows, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294272/how-do-i-install-pygtk-pygobject-on-windows-with-python-2-6

Comment: That is a Python 2 only package. If you want the Python 3 binding for GTK they are https://pypi.org/project/PyGObject

Comment: Thankyou. 
I am on a windows.
I will try it out